# InvalidSignatureException: Credential should be scoped to correct service: execute-api

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

i am implementing an AWS Lambda Function (call it the frontend function) call that calls another AWS Lambda function (call it the backend function) from its code. I use serverless. I used serverless.yml to add an event path and method for my function, using an existing API i created for the frontend function. The frontend function works fine. Calling the backend f() only works locally using serverless-offline, with the local URL given by SLS-Offline (http://localhost:3002/). When i replace that url with the AWS endpoint url for the backend f(), it fails with this error: "InvalidSignatureException: Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'execute-api'". The functions have auth=none. I've added all the possible permissions to both functions, doesn't help. Is there a place where i can specify the "correct service" when i invoke my backend f()? I couldn't find any documentation on this. I am using Slack's Bolt JS SDK and my code is in JS. Here is my invocation code, inside of my frontend handler:

```
module.exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  console.log("⚡️ Bolt app is running!");
  awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);

const lambdaBackend = new Lambda({
  apiVersion: "latest",
  region: "us-east-1",
  // endpoint needs to be set only if it deviates from the default, e.g. in a dev environment
  // process.env.SOME_VARIABLE could be set in e.g. serverless.yml for provider.environment or function.environment
  endpoint: lambda2_api_url
  
});

  const params = {
          InvocationType: 'Event', // async invocation
          FunctionName: 'serverless-function-dev-backend',
          Payload: JSON.stringify(event)
        };
  lambdaBackend.invoke(params).promise();


};
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, does the Lambda from which you call the other function has proper permissions to actually invoke the second Lambda? Also, is it mandatory in your case to directly invoke a Lambda function from another one? In most cases it's considered an antipattern